# How do print a sequence of characters (hex) as UTF8 characters in Perl?

Tags: perl, utf-8, hex

I have a variable in Perl that is just a sequence of letters and digits:

```
my $var = "48656c6c6f20576f726c64";
```

The sequence represents the string `Hello World`.

I.e. one can think of it as `0x48 0x65 0x6c 0x6c 0x6f 0x20 0x57 0x6f 0x72 0x6c 0x64`, the hex representation of `Hello World`.

How do I print `$var` as a readable UTF8?

Short: How do I print `Hello World`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With [`pack`](http://metacpan.org/pod/perlfunc#pack)

```
print pack("H*", $var);
```

or if the data really is UTF-8 encoded after it gets decoded

```
use Encode;
print Encode::decode("UTF-8", pack("H*", $var));
```

Comment: Thanks for the (quickest) answer! Works perfectly! For anyone reading this, I also added `binmode STDOUT, ":utf8";`. I had some "wide" characters

Comment: @user2426316, You should NEVER use `:utf8`. `binmode STDOUT, ":utf8";` should be `binmode STDOUT, ":encoding(UTF-8)";`, and you should also be doing the same for STDIN and STDERR. `use open ':std', ':encoding(UTF-8)';` does all of that.

Answer (score 2):

To get the text:

```
use Encode qw( decode_utf8 );

my $hex   = "48656c6c6f20576f726c64";
my $bytes = pack('H*', $hex);
my $text  = decode_utf8($bytes);
```

To print it:

```
use feature qw( say );
use open ':std', ':encoding(UTF-8)';

say $text;
```